# Corel draw, как обозначить расстояние между большим количеством объектов?

Tags: corel-draw

Иногда в работе на фрезере необходимо создать макет из простых полос между которыми должно быть одинаковое расстояние например 20мм. И таких полос надо 20 а иногда 40 и больше, и мне приходится копировать их и вручную писать координаты каждой так что бы между ними были те самые 20мм. Но даже бывают случаи когда 20мм оказывается слишком большим расстоянием и начальник говорит надо 18мм, и я опять переписываю координаты. Есть ли способ упростить этот момент хоть как нибудь?